# AngularJS controllers somehow clash

Tags: angularjs

I have an application with multiple views and controllers. Controllers are defined in separate .js files and included in the bottom of main page. However, when loading the application, one of controllers doesn't get loaded. I've simplified the issue and included full content of both JS files into a single one.

With code below I get `Argument 'ShellCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);    

    var shellCtrl = function ($scope, $log) {
    // ....

    app.controller("ShellCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", shellCtrl]);
})();

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    var svcCenterSettingsCtrl = function($log) {
    // ....

    app.controller("ServiceCenterSettingsCtrl", ["$log", svcCenterSettingsCtrl]);
})();
```

If `ServiceCenterSettingsCtrl` is registered first, then I get `Argument 'ServiceCenterSettingsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`.

However, if I register them within same self executing function like below, it works.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);    

    var shellCtrl = function ($scope, $log) {
    // ....

    app.controller("ShellCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", shellCtrl]);


    var svcCenterSettingsCtrl = function($log) {
    // ....

    app.controller("ServiceCenterSettingsCtrl", ["$log", svcCenterSettingsCtrl]);
})();
```

Is there some typo that I don't see, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: That`s because angular.module is creates new app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare app module twice in the first code sample:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

Modules can be registered only once. To reference already registered module you should remove second parameter from function:

```
var app = angular.module("app");
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it is the correct answer. Curiosity, will redeclaring the module practically overwrite anything that was associated with the previous declaration?

Comment: @JoeMinichino I think creation of module redeclaration completely overwrites previous module. Probably everyone who starts with Angular does this mistake. To me API would be much more clear if it had two functions: one for module creation, another for module retrieval.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Maybe not my place to say, but that is an awful API. In line with JavaScript though (new Array(5) and new Array(5, 6) being completely different thing).